# LINUX: multiq leaf not replaceable with tc

Tags: linux-kernel, tc, queue, traffic-management, replace

```
# uname -r   
4.7.5-200.fc24.x86_64+debug

# tc -s -d qdisc show dev ens3
qdisc mq 8001: root  
Sent 44589 bytes 340 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)  backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent 8001:1 
limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5.0ms interval 100.0ms ecn  Sent 90 bytes 1 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
[...]
qdisc fq_codel 0: parent 8001:2
limit 10240p flows 1024 quantum 1514 target 5.0ms interval
100.0ms ecn  Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) [...]
```

-> When trying to replace ...

```
# tc qdisc replace dev ens3 parent 8001 handle :1 sfq 
Error: argument ":5" is wrong: invalid qdisc ID  

# tc qdisc replace dev ens3  handle 8001:1 sfq 
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument  

# tc qdisc replace dev ens3 parent 8001 handle 1 sfq 
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

# tc qdisc replace dev ens3 parent 8001:1 sfq 
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
```

Specific qdisc is out of scope here.  Though, it makes sense, especially for older kernels, where the default qdisc is FIFO!

According code it should be possible:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/sched/sch_api.c#L1214

Sparing you **trivial tc code paths**. It simply constructs a netlink msg to the kernel from cli input.

I've not traced through yet, it might be a simple one. :)

Has anyone ever exchanged a leaf in a multiq instance? Am I getting something wrong when constructing the cli invoke?

Answer (score 2):

Well, holistically it's solvable by changing default qdisc, since mq does initialize it's leave to the default qdisc. So ...

```
sysctl -w net.core.default_qdisc=<your_qdisc>

tc qdisc replace dev <your iface> root mq
```

An verifiy ...

```
tc -s qdisc show <your iface> ens3
```

Though, individual setability would have it's charme. I might come round implementing that somewhen with growin need. :)